# Socket ends up in CLOSE_WAIT when using Jython

Tags: java, python, sockets, jython

I have run into some problems when I use Jython.
I have implemented a web service where you can upload python scripts and then use them to get data from news feeds, etc..

The problem is that my server is leaking file descriptors. Sockets ends up in CLOSE_WAIT and then never gets garbage collected.
It often works well until a news feed is down, then the server quickly runs into 'too many open files'.

In my implementation, I use org.python.util.PythonInterpreter, but I also have been able to reproduce it through jyhton CLI.
(Same problem occurs both for version 2.5.3 and 2.7b2).

I've downloaded Jython from the following URL.
http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/python/jython-standalone/2.5.3/jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar

If you run the jython CLI in one shell and then look at the socket states in another, you can see that they ends up in CLOSE_WAIT forever.

To reproduce:

```
 $ java -cp jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar org.python.util.jython
 >>> import urllib2
 >>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/notfound')
 >>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/notfound')
 >>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/notfound')
 >>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/notfound')
 >>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/notfound')
```

To check sockets:

```
 $ netstat -ant|grep CLOSE
```

Would be grateful if someone can help me to find a solution to this.

I **do not** ask for what CLOSE_WAIT means, but how to solve the problem.

How can I get a handle to the socket so that I can close it.

Have the same problem with jython version 2.7b2.

```
 $ java -cp jython-standalone-2.7-b1.jar org.python.util.jython
 >>> import contextlib, urllib2
 >>> u = 'http://www.google.com/notfound'
 >>> with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen(u)) as x:
 >>>      print x.read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.
The problem is solved by the jython development team.

http://bugs.jython.org/issue2170

Answer (score 0):

For the socket to progress out of close_wait you need to close the socket fd.

You are correct that sequences like below do not accumulate fd's in c-python but do accumulate open fd's in jython. I think this something to do with the way the jython garbage collector works. In the jython difference doc there's a note that doings like open().read() will cause problems - I suspect it's the same underlying issue.

```
>>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/').close()
>>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/').close()
>>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/').close()
>>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/').close()
>>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/').close()
>>> urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/').close()
```

The solution is to handle the error condition properly as follows (2.5 syntax);

```
try: 
  urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/not-found')
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
  e.fp.close()
```

Comment: Could you please give an example that works with jython?

Comment: amended to include an example

Comment: If the server answering '404 Not Found' then your example still leaks CLOSE_WAIT. Try 'www.google.com/notfound'.

Answer (score 0):

It means the remote party has send fin to the TCP connection but the application is yet to respond to it by closing the socket.